# Sequence Convergence Proof $a_{k} = \frac{k-1}{k+1}$ - What is $n_{o}$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

So, I have done a lot of these and they were all wrong, but I think I might have done this one correctly, so I'd like to use it as a template in my brain for future problems. I'm just not sure, if I've chosen $k$ and $n_{o}$ correctly. Does what I've done in **Step 3/4** make sense? Or is this $\frac{2}{k}$ not actual math and I should have estimated at some other value?

**Problem**

Determine the limit of $(a_{k})$ and determine an $n_{o}$ for $|a_{k}-a| <\varepsilon$ with $k\geqslant n_{o}$ for:

$a_{k} = \frac{k-1}{k+1}$

**Step 1:**
Find the limit, which is 1 (since the limit isn't my problem, I won't detail it).

**Step 2:**
After I found it, I subtracted it from  $a_{k}$ like this:

|$a_{k} - a|<\varepsilon \Leftrightarrow  |\frac{k-1}{k+1}-1|<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow  |\frac{k-1}{k+1}-\frac{k+1}{k+1}|<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow  |\frac{-2}{k+1}|<\varepsilon$

**Step 3:**
Now I have to find the $k\geqslant n_{o}$ and since $\frac{2}{k+1}\leq \frac{2}{k}$ , I just have to find an $n_{o}$, so that $\frac{2}{k}<\varepsilon$, whenever $k\geqslant n_{o}$.

Since $\frac{2}{k}<\varepsilon$ if and only if $k>\frac{2}{\varepsilon}$, then i just have to pick a $n_{o}>\frac{2}{\varepsilon}$

**Step 4:**
So we arrive at the conclusion:
$|a_{k}-a|=|\frac{k-1}{k+1}-1|=|\frac{-2}{k+1}|=\frac{2}{k+1}<\frac{2}{k}\leq \frac{2}{n_{o}}<\varepsilon$

Answer (score 0):

$n_0>\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}$ then you can take $n_0=\left[\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}\right]+1$